# LINQ DateTime Query that ignores milliseconds

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, milliseconds

`x.CreateDate` `DateTime` is stored in our database down to milliseconds.  My dateTimePicker values startdate and enddate only allows for querying down to seconds.

How can change my query to ignore the milliseconds of `x.CreateDate`?  I thought the code I wrote below would work but it is not.

```
if (stardDateIsValid && endDateIsValid && startdate == enddate)
    query = _context.Logs
        .Where(x => x.ApplicationID == applicationId &&
                    x.CreateDate.AddMilliseconds(-x.CreateDate.Millisecond) == startdate)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.ID)
        .Take(count);
```

Comment: When you say "it's not working", you should tell us in what way it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you.  It returns no results

Comment: What format is `startdate` in?

Comment: format: 'MM/DD/YYYY  h:mm:ss a'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why I could not get any results from the queries posted above as I tried several variations of their themes.  However I did get it working correctly by adding milliseconds to the startdate and enddate variables and it s working.

```
if (stardDateIsValid && endDateIsValid)
   startdate = startdate.AddMilliseconds(000);
   enddate = enddate.AddMilliseconds(999);
   query = _context.Logs.Where(x => x.ApplicationID == applicationId && x.CreateDate >= startdate && x.CreateDate <= enddate).OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).Take(count);
```

Comment: `startdate = startdate.AddMilliseconds(000);` does nothing and can be eliminated.  `enddate = enddate.AddMilliseconds(999);` can be simplified to `enddate = enddate.AddSeconds(1);` and then `x.CreateDate < enddate`

Answer (score 2):

```
var query =  from l in _context.Logs
             where l.ApplicationID == applicationId
             && SqlMethods.DateDiffSecond(l.CreateDate,startdate) == 0
             orderby l.ID descending
             select l).Take(count);
```

This avoids converting every date in you table into a string and the subsequent string comparison, by comparing the two dates as dates.

Comment: Thanks James but because l.CreateDate value includes milliseconds and startdate does not, it would never return anything if I understand correctly?  I've added the assembly reference for Sqlmethods and gave it a try.   No error but does not return any results.

Comment: @user2415620 `DateDiffSecond` is only comparing the difference in seconds.  (I tested it using the Northwind db, and a starttime of a half second after midnight)

Answer (score 1):

Getting `CreateDate` and `startdate` in the same format will help you compare apples to apples.  This should accomplish that.

```
if (stardDateIsValid && endDateIsValid && startdate == enddate)
    query = _context.Logs
        .Where(x => x.ApplicationID == applicationId &&
                    x.CreateDate.ToString(@"MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss") == startdate.ToString(@"MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss")
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.ID)
        .Take(count);
```

Comment: Thanks but it still returns no result.    `code  _context.Logs
{SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[Message] AS [Message], 
    [Extent1].[ApplicationID] AS [ApplicationID], 
    [Extent1].[CreateDate] AS [CreateDate], 
    [Extent1].[Data] AS [Data]
    FROM [dbo].[Log] AS [Extent1]}
    base: {SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[Message] AS [Message], 
    [Extent1].[ApplicationID] AS [ApplicationID], 
    [Extent1].[CreateDate] AS [CreateDate], 
    [Extent1].[Data] AS [Data]
    FROM [dbo].[Log] AS [Extent1]}
    Local: Count = 0

Comment: x.CreateDate.ToString(@"MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss") == startdate.ToString(@"MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss")

Answer (score 0):

You can create extension method.

```
public const long TicksPerMillisecond = 10000;
public const long TicksPerSecond = TicksPerMillisecond * 1000;

public static bool IsEqualIgnoreMilliseconds(this DateTime date, DateTime compareDate)
{
    long tickDiff = date.Ticks - compareDate.Ticks;
    return tickDiff > 0 ? tickDiff < TicksPerSecond : tickDiff < -TicksPerSecond;
}
```

Then you can use this:

```
if (stardDateIsValid && endDateIsValid && startdate == enddate)
    query = _context.Logs
    .Where(x => x.ApplicationID == applicationId &&
                x.CreateDate.IsEqualIgnoreMilliseconds(startdate)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.ID)
    .Take(count);
```